# Coupon Code on Checkout Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, coupon

I am currently trying to have coupon codes work on my checkout page, using the Oxygen theme. Currently I am loading both the cart and the checkout on the same page, but when using the coupon code provided by the cart, I get redirected to the cart page, which I absolutely do not want (want to stay on xxxx.com/checkout.

How can I go about removing this href, or including the coupon code solely on the checkout page without using the coupon window provided by the [woocommerce_cart]

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not traditional behavior of checkout, but it can be done. All you have to do is change the Cart Page's target Page.

1. Goto to Woocommerce settings
2. Flip to the Checkout tab
3. Under Checkout Pages, locate Cart Page
4. Change its target page to Checkout or whatever page you are using for that purpose
5. Save and Test